# How to calculate a drop rate based on percentage

Tags: java, math

I was torn between posting here and `math.stackexchange.com` but opted for here as it's equally programming related and I've not used `math.stackexchange.com` before.

Basically I have 6 different items I'd like to 'drop' based on a percentage but I have no idea how to go about implementing this. Math isn't my strong suit either which doesn't help.

Anyway, the percentages for items 1 through 6 are as follows:

`1%, 0.85%, 0.1%, 0.05%, 0.01%, 0.001%`

so item 1 has a 1% chance to drop, item 2 has a 0.85% chance to drop etc.

And I one want 1 item to drop per run, if none of these 'chances' are met then a default item will be used instead. Consider these 6 items bonus items.

So far i've tried this:

```
        Random rn = new Random();

    int x = rn.nextInt(100)+1;

    if(100%x==0)//1%
    {

    }
    if(100%(x*100)==0) //0.1%
    {

    }
```

which doesn't seem like a fair calculation and this:

```
    Random rn = new Random();

    int x = rn.nextInt(100000)+1;

    if(100%x==0)//1%
    {

    }
    if(8500%x==0) //0.1%
    {

    }
```

which seems even worse.

I was thinking of using a random number for each item but thats a lot of `RNG` as it'll be running in a game loop.

I've tried to keep this question as direct as possible to avoid debate etc so I'm not looking for the **best** solution, simply one that works - if any other information is needed, I'm happy to answer as long as it's n2k to help me with this problem =)

Comment: There is also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oooh, I didn't realise! Thanks, I'll move my question over there! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating random number for every chance is good approach :

```
    double[] chances = {1, 35, 0.85, 50, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001, 65, 11};
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean dropped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chances.length; i++) {
        if (chances[i] > r.nextDouble() * 100) {
            System.out.println("Item with " + chances[i] + " chance is dropped");
            dropped = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (dropped == false) {
        System.out.println("Dropping default item");
    }
```

Note that as long as you only drop one item, the order of elements is important.

For example, you have 5 items that drop in 99%. Logically for the fifth item there will be only (0.01^4)*0.99 chance that it drops.

Comment: Thank you for implementation example

Comment: @Timmy - You are welcome, I added one more solution + imporant note you should think about :)

Answer (score 4):

I would generate a random double between 0 and 1, and use ranges:

- between 0 and 0.01 (1%): item 1 drops
- between 0.01 and 0.0185 (1% + 0.85%): item 2 drops
- between 0.0185 and 0.0195 (1.85% + 0.1%): item 3 drops
- ...

Comment: Thank you for pseudo example, I couldn't quite wrap my head around it until I read @libik's answer but it all makes sense now - thank you. :D